# Most Recently Used Index - DS&A / Interview Question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Recently got the following question on an interview with FAANG. Could not understand for the life of me the optimal solution that the interviewer described, and after struggling with it for awhile, I've come here for help. The question is:

Design a most recently used index retriever. The retriever will be fed (in a stream) integers, and your class has to return the most recently used index for all integers that have been fed.

The class should implement two functions: `stream(x)` and `get_index(x)`.

`stream(x)` consumes the given integer x and does not return anything. `get_index(x)` returns the most recently used index of the given integer x.

Example:

```
r = Retriever()
r.stream(1)
r.stream(2)
r.get_index(1) # should return 1
r.get_index(2) # should return 0 since it's the most recently used
r.stream(1) 
r.get_index(1) # should return 0 since it was most recently used in the previous line
```

Another example with duplicates:

```
r = Retriever()
r.stream(1)
r.stream(2)
r.stream(2)
r.get_index(1) # should return 1, not 2
```

Pretty simple, right? The tough part that I'm struggling with, is how to get the optimal solution, which apparently can implement both `stream` and `get_index` in O(logN) time.

All I have going on is the fact that the interviewer mentioned that it is possible with a Binary Tree.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem (it's very possible that I am, I had to read your post something like 10 times before I understood anything), I think all you need is a simple map integers -> time last seen; plus one counter that indicates the current "time". Then `get_index` simply returns the difference between the current time and the time last seen. A map can be implemented using a hashmap or a binary tree.

Comment: Are you sure you've explained the question correctly? Using a map, both functions can be done in `O(1)` time

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "most recently used index".  After `stream(1); stream(2); stream(2);`, does `get_index(1)` return 1 or 2?

Comment: @MattTimmermans in that case, get_index(1) should return 1. get_index(2) should return 0

Comment: trincot's answer is the kind of thing the interviewer was looking for, then.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a balanced, threaded binary tree (like AVL) and enrich each node with a `size` attribute that should always represent the number of nodes in its subtree (including itself). Unlike with binary search trees, an insertion always happens at the left-most leaf, where the new node becomes its left child. This way that new node has index 1 at that moment. By rebalancing (e.g. AVL rotations) the tree remains balanced.

Accompany this with a hash map that maps a value to a node in the tree. If a value is streamed again, this map will point to the node, which can then be removed (using AVL mechanics -- don't forget size updates in the ancestor nodes). After this removal, it is inserted again as would happen with a new value.

To get the node at a given index, one can walk down the tree, using the `size` information to choose the correct child, and eventually find the right node and corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep track of the current "time". The "time" is just a counter that increments by 1 when an integer is fed.
- Maintain a map: integer -> time last fed.
- The index of an integer is just the difference between the current time, and the time this integer was fed.

A map can be implemented either as a hashmap, or as a binary tree.

Below is an implementation of class `Retriever` in python. The map is a python `dict`, which is a hashmap behind the scene.

```py
class Retriever:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_time = 0
        self.time_last_seen = {}
    def feed(self, x):
        self.current_time += 1
        self.time_last_seen[x] = self.current_time
    def get_index(self, x):
        if x in self.time_last_seen:
            return self.current_time - self.time_last_seen[x]
        else:
            raise KeyError(x)

r = Retriever()
r.feed(1)
r.feed(2)
print( r.get_index(1) ) #  1
print( r.get_index(2) ) #  0
r.feed(1) 
print( r.get_index(1) ) #  0
r.feed(3)
r.feed(1)
r.feed(1)
print( r.get_index(3) ) #  2
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Stef. However, this fails for the following test case: 
`r.feed(3); r.feed(1) ;r.feed(1); r.get_index(3)` Your's returns 2. It should return 1 as the most recently used index of 1 is 0, and the most recently used index of 3 is 1 (after 0)

Comment: @peterkim95 I added your counter-example at the end of the answer. I'm afraid you're going to have to go with a more complex data structure if that's how indices behave.